# How does twitter.com open when i type x.com in browser url search?

Tags: browser

How does twitter.com open when I type x.com in browser url search, How browser able to open other url i.e twitter.com even when i type in x.com ?

**Will this lead to cheating or scams if browser allows this way redirecting to someother URL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser does the redirect, but `x.com` decides what to redirect to. You can buy a domain name and have that domainname redirect to another domain.

The browser does not decide this, nor does the target of the redirect.